# How to pass stopwords from a column of dataframe

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, nlp

I am getting error while  I directly  passing dataframe  column into stopword.
How Can I resolve this

```
    stop_words_corpus=pd.DataFrame(word_dictionary_corpus.Word.unique(),columns=feature_names)

cv = CountVectorizer( max_features = 200,analyzer='word',stop_words= stop_words_corpus) 
cv_txt = cv.fit_transform(data.pop('Clean_addr'))

****Updated Error***
```

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
        867 
        868         vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents,
    --> 869                                           self.fixed_vocabulary_)
        870 
        871         if self.binary:

```
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in _count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab)
    783             vocabulary.default_factory = vocabulary.__len__
    784 
--> 785         analyze = self.build_analyzer()
    786         j_indices = []
    787         indptr = _make_int_array()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in build_analyzer(self)
    260 
    261         elif self.analyzer == 'word':
--> 262             stop_words = self.get_stop_words()
    263             tokenize = self.build_tokenizer()
    264 


I fixed the error taht error still having the issue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cv = CountVectorizer(max_features = 200,
                     analyzer='word',
                     stop_words=stop_words_corpus.stack().unique())
```

Comment: didnt work got Keyerror   .Updating Error  in question

Comment: @ShanyEapen, please post a complete error traceback to your question

Comment: @ShanyEapen, that means there is no `Clean_addr` column in the `data` DF. What does `data.columns.tolist()` return?

Comment: ['Resi',
 'Co_Name',
 'Lat',
 'Lng',
 'Cust_ID',
 'Qty',
 'Phone',
 'Shpr_ID',
 'Weight',
 'Resi_Cnt',
 'Buz_Cnt',
 'Nearby_Cnt',
 'Resi_Ratio',
 'Resi_Area',
 'Adj_Addr',
 'Product',
 'parseNumber',
 'removeString',
 'Phone_Type',
 'Shpr_Resi_Ratio']

Comment: @ShanyEapen, yeah, Pandas usually says truth ;-)

Comment: I fixed that  got new error :make it an array error

Answer (score 0):

We need to make the  dataframe into `NpArray` to pass stopwords in to the countvectorizer

```
stop_word =stop_words_corpus['Word'].values

cv = CountVectorizer(max_features = 200,
                     analyzer='word',
                     stop_words=stop_word)
```